# Screen does not blank completely in powersave

Tags: gnome, 20.04, xorg, display, power-management

On my Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 20.04, using the default Gnome shell, I've set the "Blank screen" timeout to 5 minutes. However, the screen does not blank completely, but still shows a black image with the mouse cursor visible.

When I run `xset dpms force off` in the shell, the displays turn off properly and go to powersave mode. After the blank screen timeout kicks in, the displays actually turn back on again to show the black image with cursor. Any ideas how to enable proper powersaving here?

P.S. I already checked [Blank screen not properly blank](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296505/blank-screen-not-properly-blank) and this seems to be different, as xset doesn't work in that case.

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same issue. My power settings have Blank Screen set to 15 minutes (Dim Screen When Inactive and Automatic Suspend are turned off). When the screen goes blank, the mouse pointer is still visible. Wondering if this is a feature or a bug.

Comment: Well, I "solved" this by switching to a different dock. The issue was that the external screen going into powersave triggered a hotplug event, which woke the screen up again...